# How to call method of StatefulWidget class from another StatefulWidget class flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am working on a Flutter app project, where I need to call one method of StatefulWidget class on a different StatefulWidget class.

Please find the below code:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
    
    void clickEventTab(int index) {
    if (index == 0) {
      setState(() {
        ConstClass.currentScreen = HomeFragment();
        ConstClass.currentTab = 0;
      });
    } else if (index == 1) {
      setState(() {
        ConstClass.currentScreen = LoginFargment();
        ConstClass.currentTab = 1;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Now I need to call this `clickEventTab(int index)` method from the different class which mentioned below:

```
class Profile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProfileState createState() => _ProfileState();
}

class _ProfileState extends State<Profile> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            height: double.infinity,
            width: double.infinity,
            GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                      // Need to call clickEventTab(1) from the HomeScreenNew class
                },
                child: Container(
                    height: 40.0,
                    width: 150.0,
                    color: Colors.red,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text('Call HomeScreen'),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Can you please help me with how can I call that method `clickEventTab()` of HomeScreen class from the Profile class Container click event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this  It worked for me;

```
class Profile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProfileState createState() => _ProfileState();
}

class _ProfileState extends State<Profile> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            height: double.infinity,
            width: double.infinity,
            GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                     HomeScreen().createState().clickEventTab(1);
                },
                child: Container(
                    height: 40.0,
                    width: 150.0,
                    color: Colors.red,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text('Call HomeScreen'),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```